# Proximo Add On is not working on Heroku - Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: heroku, jruby, proximo

I have done all things according to proximo documentation and I used the proximo wrapper with my JRuby application. However it's not working. I got an error message below

```
Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Cannot assign requested address - bind - Cannot assign requested address
```

I removed and added proximo add on - not working 
I used all configuration parameters with puma - not working

My application is running without bin/proximo but with bin/proximo is not working. Here is my full log output.

```
2013-11-04T09:49:38.388041+00:00 app[web.2]: Puma 2.6.0 starting...
2013-11-04T09:49:38.388041+00:00 app[web.2]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
2013-11-04T09:49:38.388192+00:00 app[web.2]: * Environment: production
2013-11-04T09:49:38.388328+00:00 app[web.2]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:13433
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393084+00:00 app[web.2]: Exiting
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393708+00:00 app[web.2]: Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Cannot assign requested address - bind - Cannot assign requested address
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393708+00:00 app[web.2]:         initialize at org/jruby/ext/socket/RubyTCPServer.java:118
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393708+00:00 app[web.2]:                new at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:856
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393708+00:00 app[web.2]:   add_tcp_listener at /app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/puma-2.6.0-java/lib/puma/binder.rb:190
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393708+00:00 app[web.2]:   add_tcp_listener at (eval):2
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393708+00:00 app[web.2]:                run at /app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/puma-2.6.0-java/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:33
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393708+00:00 app[web.2]:              start at /app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393708+00:00 app[web.2]:              start at /app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393708+00:00 app[web.2]:             (root) at /app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393708+00:00 app[web.2]:                tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1860
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393866+00:00 app[web.2]:             (root) at /app/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393866+00:00 app[web.2]:            require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
2013-11-04T09:49:38.393866+00:00 app[web.2]:             (root) at script/rails:6
2013-11-04T09:49:39.993189+00:00 heroku[web.2]: Process exited with status 1
2013-11-04T09:49:40.004841+00:00 heroku[web.2]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo#using-the-proximo-wrapper

"The Proximo wrapper does not work with JVM based applications including Java, Scala, Clojure, Groovy and JRuby. See below for an example of configuring a JVM application to forward traffic across a SOCKS proxy."